# Did I loose my BCH and BTG?

Tags: private-key

I had bitcoin in the blockchain info wallet till after both the BCH and BTG forks. I sent that bitcoin out to a paper wallet. If I sweep that paper wallet now, should there be BCH and BTG on there along with the BTC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the private key from the wallet that had BTC in it on both forks. Sending the funds to a new wallet is the right thing to do, now only step you need to do is import the private key into BCH BTG wallets, and if you had BTC on 28 dec on the B2X fork you can also import your key into the b2x wallet.

Comment: Brother, your info was so important to me. Thank you. I was searching for hours and not a single video or text I read explained that. Thank you. If you care for a tip, give me a public address for BCH. You diserve it.

Comment: you can mark it as answer if you believe it helped you

Comment: Where can you obtain BTG ?  Or import wallet to obtain BTG? Or did we miss out already? @Sandro